# Proper SE for simulation software related questions

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I was wondering what the right SE subsite to ask questions related to the use of simulation software (like Zemax, ASAP, Comsol and many more) is and if there is such a subsite? Such questions do not fall into [physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), since they are not really about physics. An example question would be

> How can I do smth. in Zemax?

or

> What is a good version control system for [some program] projects?

Answer (score 1):

What you'd need is a SE site for the *field* that users of this software are working in. A quick google suggests these are all heavyweight optical simulators, which makes me think this isn't going to be a big enough field to have a SE site already, if [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) doesn't cover it.

There's the [Optics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44685/optics) proposal on Area 51 (indeed, one of the sample questions is "How to [do smth. tricky] in Zemax|OSLO|CODE V?"), but it's got some way to go...

Comment: Well, for example optical simulation can be used by designers, photographers, lithography engineers, and an undergrad student planning his experiment. Same with CAD software used by architects and fine mechanics designers. I believe there is a lot of common between simulation tools and uses, independent from the actual field they are working in. I am now wondering if proposing a simulation SE would be a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

For version control, you can probably head over to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

For some reason, they seem to know something about that stuff.

Comment: I wonder if they will also understand me if I say "Zemax files" though. I'd really like to address other Zemax (or other simulation programs) users. It should be quite a big community.